# ajax call url wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

js file in content/themes/themename/js/main.js
in this file I am trying to do an ajax call to this file content/themes/themename/lib/file.php

this is how my ajax call looks like

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function(result) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        console.log(data.name);
        }
    });
```

but the url is not working anyone can help me out?

I have tried ../lib/file.php too

Comment: check the php file path.

Comment: Read this -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

Comment: it's this path: /content/themes/themename/lib/getsearchoptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/lib/file.php',
    success: function(result) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        console.log(data.name);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with the path that relative to the root directory
ex :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/themename/lib/file.php',
    success: function(result) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        console.log(data.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this in my body tag of my header.php file

```
data-theme-url="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```

and use the url in my javascript like this

```
url: $('body').data('theme-url') + '/lib/file.php',
```